# Does inline asm access to shared variables count as a data race in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, atomic, lock-free

```
#include <thread>
int i;
int main()
{
    std::thread t1([&i]() {
        asm volatile("movl $1, %0"
                     : "=m"(i));
    });
    std::thread t2([&i]() {
        asm volatile("movl $2, %0"
                     : "=m"(i));
    });
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a data race (  and in result UB) in C++? Let's assume that address of `i` is aligned and that on our CPU load/store of aligned double words are atomic.

Probably, it satisfies a defintion of data race.

Comment: The meaning of `asm` statements is implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes it is a race condition but not a bug in this case as you don't rely on the order of the result. As Kerrek pointed out _asm_ is implementation defined (it is documented by the compiler developer), not undefined behavior.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, it is a data race and it is safe because of atomicity, yeah?

Comment: The example given in the question is not a good one. At least, it is not a particularly instructive one. As has been pointed out, you do not rely on the order of the result, so although there is a race condition, it is merely theoretical and cannot manifest itself in a bug. It is not clear to me how atomicity is relevant here.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is anything about interfacing C++ with other languages that isn't implementation defined?

Comment: @curiousguy: Depends what you mean. "C language linkage" is somewhat defined.

Comment: The program doesn't do anything remotely significant so it's hard to see where you are going.

Comment: @KerrekSB Linkage is defined in C++, linking with C is not defined and cannot be defined as there is no C/C++ std and the C++ doesn't defer to the C std for definition of C like stuff. There is the intuition and then there is the spec. As usual, **intuition matters more** and should be followed by compiler writers, and the intuition says that there is a C/C++ with all the common constructs. But in the spec, you have nothing. **There is not one strictly conformant program with both C and C++ code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard leaves inline asm implementation-defined, for obvious reasons.  To say anything about this, we have to make stuff up and hand-wave about things.

More importantly, we're no longer considering pure ISO C++, but rather the GNU dialect of C++, which defines a lot of behaviour that ISO C++ leaves Undefined.  e.g. [the gcc manual says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html) type-punning by writing one union member and reading another is well-defined in GNU C++, even though it's UB in ISO C++.  A lot of things are still UB in GNU C++, and "whatever g++ actually does" doesn't count as a definition.  See [the manual's implementation-defined behaviour section in the table of contents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Implementation).

The C++ -> asm stage of gcc doesn't even understand the instructions in an inline-asm statement, it just fills in the operands and passes it on to the assembler.  It doesn't "think about" what the instructions are doing; it treats it as a black box described by the output, input, and clobber constraints.

Since you used an `"=m"(i)` output operand, your asm statement *does* interact with the C++ variable in a C++ish way (rather than behind the compiler's back with `asm("mov $1, i");`).  I think the compiler sees it as something like `i = __builtin_my_asm_statement();`.  Plus the `volatile` keyword that prevents compile-time reordering / hoisting / dead-code-elimination.

---

Not every data race is a C++-standard Undefined-Behaviour causing Data Race.  For example, if `i` was a std::atomic type, the final value of `i` is still indeterminate because of the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).  (The program would be free of C++ UB, though, and `i` would be either 2 or 1, with no tearing.  Undefined Behaviour technically means anything could happen, of course.)

---

So, **what can we say about this code**:

- We can assume that `i` is naturally aligned, because all the usual x86 ABIs guarantee that.
- We know that the asm will include a store to memory as a single instruction, not copying one byte at a time.  (Which no sane compiler would do anyway).
- I'm *not* 100% sure that we can guarantee that the store goes directly to the shared value of `i`, rather than to scratch space on the stack which the compiler will then copy from.  An evil compiler that did this would break a *lot* of code, including anything like the Linux kernel that uses inline asm to run `lock`ed instructions on shared variables using memory operands.

So if we can assume a non-malicious compiler, we can be pretty sure what the compiler output will do.  Or perhaps the behaviour of an `"=m"` operand on a shared value should be considered well-defined behaviour in GNU C, so we can say that this is well-defined.

Comment: I started writing this when the question was posted, but never got back to it!

Comment: While a compiler could conceivably add a temporary in some cases for an output argument of an `asm` statement (or a call out an ADA function with OUT argument), introducing temporaries for IN/OUT arguments wouldn't make sense.